# Anime looks flickery on my monitor

Tags: video, display

This is a $300 monitor (144hz freesync) connected to a laptop.

This is probably not an issue exclusive to anime, but it is extremely apparent when viewing anime. If there is a static scene (say, a character standing in a field) and the camera is sliding to the right, it will look like the character is vibrating across the screen. I know that anime isn't supposed to look very smooth, but there is something particularly unsmooth, because it looks like it should on the laptop's own screen.

I would appreciate any insight, or if someone can find a better way to describe the problem I am trying to describe, so I can formulate my question better if i can't solve it here.

Comment: What fps is the video encoded at? What video player are you using? For that matter, what _OS_ are you using?

Comment: 24fps, Pot player MPC-HC VLC all video players look the same. Win10. I think this is related to the monitor. If i use my old 60Hz monitor it looks fine.

Comment: what video card do you have? is the video x264 or x265? I had some issues with x265 stuff at first, and tracked it down to my intel gma driver configuration. what media are you connecting the monitor through? HDMI/DP? I don't know if USB is low latency enough for video out.

Comment: its 264, i tried dp and hdmi, no difference